# Extension of a finite field to a finite non commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-fields, noncommutative-algebra, finite-rings

> Can a finite field be extended to non-commutative finite rings so that not all elements of the field commutes with the elements of the ring?

I have been trying this taking the examples of matrices.

Comment: I'm sure there is some horrible looking object you could cook up. Is there a reason why you'd want a ring like this?

Comment: Not any reason. Just a simple thought.

Comment: @Mathmo123 We're used to elements of fields being central, even sometimes in the context of algebras over fields which may be noncommutative, so it'd be instructive to see what it looks like when this doesn't happen. For instance $\Bbb C$ is not central in $\Bbb H$ (the quaternions).

Answer (score 6):

Let $K(\alpha)/K$ be an algebraic extension of fields, and suppose $\alpha$ has minimal polynomial $f(x)$ over the base field $K$, with $\deg f(x)=n$ (with $n\ge2$). Let $A\in M_n(K)$ be the companion matrix associated to $f(x)\in K[x]$. Then the there is an isomorphic copy of $K(\alpha)$, call it $L$, sitting inside the matrix algebra $M_n(K)$, which the unital $K$-subalgebra generated by $A$. Then the field extension $L/K$ can be extended to $M_n(K)/K$ with $L$ not central in $M_n(K)$ (since for instance the element $A\in L$ does not commute with the diagonal matrix $\mathrm{diag}(1,0,\cdots,0)$.)

Answer (score 5):

If you don't care about mapping $1$ to $1$, then we can embed any field $K$ into the ring $A$ of $2\times 2$ matrices over $K$, by sending $a\in K$ to $\begin{pmatrix}a & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.  This preserves addition and multiplication, and $K$ clearly this does not lie in the center of $A$.

If you care about mapping $1$ to $1$, then we have to be more careful.  If $K$ is a prime field, this is impossible.  But if we can write $K=L(\alpha)$ for some field $L$ and $\alpha$ algebraic of degree $d>1$ over $L$, then we can let $A$ be the ring of $d\times d$ matrices over $L$, with $L$ identified with multiples of the identity matrix, and map $\alpha$ to a matrix with the same minimal polynomial as $\alpha$.

In particular, a finite field of order $q=p^n$, with $n\geq 2$, has a non-central embedding into the ring of $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{F}_p$.